# Indexing Pandas DataFrame using variable

Tags: python, pandas

If i have a dataframe called df I can select rows 1 to 4, using this df[1:4]

But I can't do it like this (it is possible in R)

a=[1:4]

df[a]

Is this possible in Pandas?

Comment: `a=[1:4]` is not valid python syntax so I'm not sure how you have a practical problem that would boil down to wanting to do this. Though, it did make me sit back for a second and think that it's not an unreasonable feature :)

Comment: yeah but something like this basically I have several dataframes that all need to be updated throughout the code. But it would be great just to change the range once

Comment: `a = slice(1, 4)`. For more complicated slices you can use [pd.IndexSlice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.IndexSlice.html).

Comment: ok thanks. I've done it like this in R:  a=c(1:100)
  df=df[a,]

Comment: Actually, the suggestion by @ayhan is _much_ better

Comment: thanks ayhan. I'll give that a go